# Can I apply for the remaining days of 90/180 if I have not used them in expired visa

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Previous VISA info (type of VISA C):

From 14.02.2013 to 14.05.2013. Duration of stay - 90 days. Number of entries - 2.

I crossed the Schengen on 16.02.2013 for my first entry, so 180 days expire on 14.08.2013.

Trips:
1) From 16.02.2013 to 31.03.2013 (44 days)
2) From 17.04.2013 to 13.05.2013 (27 days)

Total number of days in Norway: 71.

Total number of days in Ukraine between two trips: 19.

**May I apply for the VISA from 13.07.2013 to 01.08.2013 and stay in Norway for 19 days before 01.08.2013?**

Comment: Till when is your (multi entry) Schengen Visa valid? What matters is that you can stay for 90 days in any 180 day period, and a new 180 day period starts when the previous expires. So if your visa is still valid you should not have to apply for a new one.

Comment: No, it's not valid. That's the thing, the visa was issued for 90 days (not the 180 or half a year) and I did not use them so I want to apply for the remaining 19 days.